# Create image from ascii value

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64, ascii

I am new to *base64* images. I have a problem that *base64* images are not completely supported in `IE8` or lower, with a limitation of `32Kb`.

Finally, I got a function to convert `base64` images to `ascii` code using `javascript`. However, I am not able to figure out how to show a `img` using `ascii` value of the image.

when we use `base64` in `img` tag we write like this,

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..." />
```

Therefore, I need something using which if I have an `ascii` code of an image, I can display it the similar way I am displaying `base64` image image.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'ascii code of an image'?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: it is the same text which you will see it you open a `.jpg` or `.png` or any other image file in notepad

Comment: Still your question is unclear. Do you mean you need the string representation in base64 of your image bytes?

Comment: no, I have the ascii value of the image, I need to show it on HTML page. `<img src="test.jpg" />` instead `src` I need to give the ascii value of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the limitations of IE8.

IE8 only supports images [with a maximum size of 32KB](http://caniuse.com/datauri), not 32 bits. The only thing you can do about it is delivering images that are at most 32KB big. Or drop the support for IE8 is that is an option.

In answer of your second question:

set the src attribute of the image using JavaScript:

```
function changeImage(dataAsBase64String)
{
    image1.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataAsBase64String;
}
```